# Removing selected items in combobox ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have been trying to find a code which can remove the selected items from a combobox for next records. My combobox´s name is FZ and my form saves records for tblPrägen. My combobox gets the data from a table that named as tblFixieren. I am getting syntax error from Access. To be honest, i am not sure whether this code works or not. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

With FZ

.RowSourceType = "Value List"

.RowSource = _
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT tblFixieren.ZahnID_Fix 
FROM tblFixieren WHERE tblFixieren.Zahntyp_Fix Like  F* ").GetString(adClipString, -1, , ",")

End With
End Sub

Private Sub FZ_Click()

FZ.RemoveItem FZ.ListIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA does not have GetString() function. That is VB.net. If you are using VB.net, correct your tags.

Comment: Enclose your `Like` pattern with quotes.  And since you're executing the statement with ADO, use `%` instead of `*` as the wild card.  `" ... WHERE tblFixieren.Zahntyp_Fix Like 'F%'"`

Comment: Hi, my code gets now another error.tThe arguments are of the wrong type, are out of scope, or are incompatible with each other.(Runtime Error 3001)

Comment: What happens if you test with this set of GetString options? `GetString(2, , , ",")`

Comment: Hi, now i am getting this error (You entered a value that is not valid for this field.).